# css animation using keyframe not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, easing

I have come accross this problem and don't understand the behaviour.

Here we have a simple rectangle that should animate in and out on the press of the toggle button.

When the button is clicked, the rectangle class name will be toggled between 'animation-in' and 'animation-out'.

The keyframe object for 'scale-easeInOutBounce' and 'scale-easeInOutBounce-out' is identical, only the name reference is different between the two.

Everything works perfectly.

When the property 'animation-name:' within the css rule'.animation-out' is changed from 'scale-easeInOutBounce-out' to 'scale-easeInOutBounce' the animation breaks.

The question here is, why does this occur? Is there a logic error in the code, or an incorrect implementation of animation?

Would love to understand this behaviour.

This behaviour was replicated using 'Chrome' on Windows 11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rectangle Animation</title>
    <style>
        #myRectangle {
            width: 100px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: green;
            margin: 20px;
            transform: scale(0);
            
        }

        .animation-out {
            animation-duration: 4s;
            animation-timing-function: ease; /*linear*/
            animation-delay: 0s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-direction: normal;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-play-state: running;
            animation-name: scale-easeInOutBounce;
            animation-timeline: auto;
            animation-range-start: normal;
            animation-range-end: normal;
        }

        .animation-in {
            animation-duration: 4s;
            animation-timing-function: ease;
            animation-delay: 0s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-direction: reverse;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-play-state: running;
            animation-name: scale-easeInOutBounce;
            animation-timeline: auto;
            animation-range-start: normal;
            animation-range-end: normal;
        }

        @keyframes scale-easeInOutBounce {
            0% { transform: scale(1); }
            2% { transform: scale(0.99); }
            4% { transform: scale(1); }
            10% { transform: scale(0.97); }
            14% { transform: scale(0.99); }
            22% { transform: scale(0.88); }
            32% { transform: scale(0.99); }
            42% { transform: scale(0.6); }
            50% { transform: scale(0.5); }
            58% { transform: scale(0.4); }
            68% { transform: scale(0.01); }
            78% { transform: scale(0.12); }
            86% { transform: scale(0.01); }
            90% { transform: scale(0.03); }
            96% { transform: scale(0); }
            98% { transform: scale(0.01); }
            100% { transform: scale(0); }
        }

        @keyframes scale-easeInOutBounce-out {
            0% { transform: scale(1); }
            2% { transform: scale(0.99); }
            4% { transform: scale(1); }
            10% { transform: scale(0.97); }
            14% { transform: scale(0.99); }
            22% { transform: scale(0.88); }
            32% { transform: scale(0.99); }
            42% { transform: scale(0.6); }
            50% { transform: scale(0.5); }
            58% { transform: scale(0.4); }
            68% { transform: scale(0.01); }
            78% { transform: scale(0.12); }
            86% { transform: scale(0.01); }
            90% { transform: scale(0.03); }
            96% { transform: scale(0); }
            98% { transform: scale(0.01); }
            100% { transform: scale(0); }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myRectangle"></div>
<button id="toggleButton">Toggle Animation</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById('toggleButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var rectangle = document.getElementById('myRectangle');
        if (rectangle.classList.contains('animation-in')) {
            rectangle.classList.remove('animation-in');
            rectangle.classList.add('animation-out');
        } else {
            rectangle.classList.remove('animation-out');
            rectangle.classList.add('animation-in');
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/midnightstudios/vajqdcLo/2/

Here is the code that is broken:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rectangle Animation</title>
    <style>
        #myRectangle {
            width: 100px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: green;
            margin: 20px;
            transform: scale(0);
            
        }

        .animation-out {
            animation-duration: 4s;
            animation-timing-function: ease; /*linear*/
            animation-delay: 0s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-direction: normal;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-play-state: running;
            animation-name: scale-easeInOutBounce;
            animation-timeline: auto;
            animation-range-start: normal;
            animation-range-end: normal;
        }

        .animation-in {
            animation-duration: 4s;
            animation-timing-function: ease;
            animation-delay: 0s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-direction: reverse;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-play-state: running;
            animation-name: scale-easeInOutBounce;
            animation-timeline: auto;
            animation-range-start: normal;
            animation-range-end: normal;
        }

        @keyframes scale-easeInOutBounce {
            0% { transform: scale(1); }
            2% { transform: scale(0.99); }
            4% { transform: scale(1); }
            10% { transform: scale(0.97); }
            14% { transform: scale(0.99); }
            22% { transform: scale(0.88); }
            32% { transform: scale(0.99); }
            42% { transform: scale(0.6); }
            50% { transform: scale(0.5); }
            58% { transform: scale(0.4); }
            68% { transform: scale(0.01); }
            78% { transform: scale(0.12); }
            86% { transform: scale(0.01); }
            90% { transform: scale(0.03); }
            96% { transform: scale(0); }
            98% { transform: scale(0.01); }
            100% { transform: scale(0); }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myRectangle"></div>
<button id="toggleButton">Toggle Animation</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById('toggleButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var rectangle = document.getElementById('myRectangle');
        if (rectangle.classList.contains('animation-in')) {
            rectangle.classList.remove('animation-in');
            rectangle.classList.add('animation-out');
        } else {
            rectangle.classList.remove('animation-out');
            rectangle.classList.add('animation-in');
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain the cause of the behavior and what you can do to fix it.

**Cause**

The reason the outward animation appears to break is because it actually seems to start in the middle of it. More specifically—if you hit the button, the inward animation will play for 4 seconds, right? Then let's say you wait 8 seconds before hitting the button a second time. For some reason, the outward animation will start 12 seconds into its animation. As proof, try setting the duration of the outward animation to 20 seconds and try hitting the buttons again. You'll notice that the outward animation starts partway in.

**Solution**

If you wanted to keep using the same animation name and keep your code the way it is, one solution is actually to add a delay before you add the classes. I edited the example and showed it below. You could for example use something like `setTimeout(() => rectangle.classList.add('animation-out'), 0)`, but a better function to use would be `requestAnimationFrame()` because it minimizes the delay.

```js
document.getElementById('toggleButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var rectangle = document.getElementById('myRectangle');
        if (rectangle.classList.contains('animation-in')) {
            rectangle.classList.remove('animation-in');
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {rectangle.classList.add('animation-out');})
            
        } else {
            rectangle.classList.remove('animation-out');
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {rectangle.classList.add('animation-in');})
        }
    });
```

```css
#myRectangle {
            width: 100px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: green;
            margin: 20px;
            transform: scale(0);
        }

.animation-out {
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: scale-easeInOutBounce;
}

.animation-in {
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: scale-easeInOutBounce;
}

@keyframes scale-easeInOutBounce {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  2% { transform: scale(0.99); }
  4% { transform: scale(1); }
  10% { transform: scale(0.97); }
  14% { transform: scale(0.99); }
  22% { transform: scale(0.88); }
  32% { transform: scale(0.99); }
  42% { transform: scale(0.6); }
  50% { transform: scale(0.5); }
  58% { transform: scale(0.4); }
  68% { transform: scale(0.01); }
  78% { transform: scale(0.12); }
  86% { transform: scale(0.01); }
  90% { transform: scale(0.03); }
  96% { transform: scale(0); }
  98% { transform: scale(0.01); }
  100% { transform: scale(0); }
}

@keyframes scale-easeInOutBounce-out {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  2% { transform: scale(0.99); }
  4% { transform: scale(1); }
  10% { transform: scale(0.97); }
  14% { transform: scale(0.99); }
  22% { transform: scale(0.88); }
  32% { transform: scale(0.99); }
  42% { transform: scale(0.6); }
  50% { transform: scale(0.5); }
  58% { transform: scale(0.4); }
  68% { transform: scale(0.01); }
  78% { transform: scale(0.12); }
  86% { transform: scale(0.01); }
  90% { transform: scale(0.03); }
  96% { transform: scale(0); }
  98% { transform: scale(0.01); }
  100% { transform: scale(0); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rectangle Animation</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myRectangle"></div>
<button id="toggleButton">Toggle Animation</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Why the behavior occurs in the first place? I do not know for sure. In general, you can expect some pretty weird behavior when it comes to swapping out keyframes in various circumstances (whether it involves pure CSS or the JavaScript WAAPI)—I can speak from personal experience on that. In this case, maybe swapping out the classes immediately makes it get confused and think that it's just swapping out the keyframes for a singular animation instead of swapping out the animation entirely, so it erroneously keeps the duration going instead of starting from 0?

Comment: I really like your feedback, thank you. I just want to make it clear, the issue is that one should not have to use two different animations (names) when they are exactly the same. One should be able to use 'scale-easeInOutBounce' for both 'in' and 'out' animations, and the problem I am describing is, that when I do, the animation breaks.  I will explore your solution.

Comment: @JacquesJoubert Of course! I did mix some minor thing up during my explanation (I gave the solution using the same animation name as desired, but I mentioned using the "separate animation name"), but I fixed it just now. Hopefully that did not cause too much confusion—everything else is the same.

Comment: Thank you, truly. I appreciate your time and feedback on this.

Comment: In your code snippet, you did forget 'rectangle.classList.add('animation-in');' I think you meant to remove it, else is is dupplicated.

Comment: @JacquesJoubert Thanks for pointing that out—I've removed the extra line.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the smoothness of the animation. I have made some CSS changes here, maybe your problem will be solved.

```js
 document.getElementById('toggleButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var rectangle = document.getElementById('myRectangle');
        if (rectangle.classList.contains('animation-in')) {
            rectangle.classList.remove('animation-in');
            rectangle.classList.add('animation-out');
        } else {
            rectangle.classList.remove('animation-out');
            rectangle.classList.add('animation-in');
        }
    });
```

```css
#myRectangle{
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:green;
  margin:20px;
  transform:scale(0);
}
.animation-out, .animation-in{
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-timing-function:ease;
  animation-delay:0s;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-play-state:running;
}
.animation-out{
  animation-direction:normal;
  animation-name:scale-easeInOutBounce-out;
}
.animation-in{
  animation-direction:reverse;
  animation-name:scale-easeInOutBounce;
}
@keyframes scale-easeInOutBounce{
  0%{transform:scale(1);}
  100%{transform:scale(0);}
}

@keyframes scale-easeInOutBounce-out {
0% { transform: scale(1); }
100% { transform: scale(0); }
}
```

```html
<div id="myRectangle"></div>
  <button id="toggleButton">Toggle Animation</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The animation (keyframes) I presented is intended to be this way. Like I explained before, what I would like to achieve is to use only 'scale-easeInOutBounce' and as such remove 'scale-easeInOutBounce-out'